I want a more detailed square using pytesseract
I want to make a code to extract the x-axis numbers and x-axis labels in the chart. I hope the numbers and labels are separated. Is there a way to solve it?
Recognize the x-axis y-axis and classify it based on the axis. I think the box is drawn incorrectly.
enter image description here
def getXTextFromImageArray(image, mode):
    image_text = []

    if mode == 'x-text':
        image = cv2.transpose(image)
        config = "-l eng --oem 1 --psm 11"
    elif mode == 'x-labels':
        config = "-l eng --oem 1 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=.0123456789"

    d = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, config = config, output_type = Output.DICT)

    n_boxes = len(d['text'])

    # Pick only the positive confidence boxes
    for i in range(n_boxes):

        if int(d['conf'][i]) >= 0:

            text = d['text'][i].strip()

            (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
            image_text.append((d['text'][i], (x, y, w, h)))

    # Remove all the duplicates in (text, box) pairs
    return list(set(image_text))

for path in Path(img_dir).iterdir():
    if path.name.endswith('.png') or path.name.endswith('.jpg') or path.name.endswith('.jpeg'):

        filepath = img_dir + "/" + path.name
        image = cv2.imread(filepath)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        height, width, channels = image.shape
        xaxis, yaxis, upper = detectAxes(filepath)
        y_text, y_labels = [], []
        x_text, x_labels = [], []

        for (x1, y1, x2, y2) in [xaxis]:
            xaxis = (x1, y1, x2, y2)

        for (x1, y1, x2, y2) in [yaxis]:
            yaxis = (x1, y1, x2, y2)

        for (x1, y1, x2, y2) in [upper]:
            upper = (x1, y1, x2, y2)

        rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 4
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)

        # Make a backward pass to skip the ticks
        gray = maskImageBackwardPassX(filepath, xaxis[1])

        # Processing the image so that the contours are drawn to labels and text
        retX, threshX = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU | cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        rect_kernelX = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 15))
        threshX = cv2.dilate(threshX, rect_kernelX, iterations = 1)
        rect_kernelX = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 1))
        threshX = cv2.dilate(threshX, rect_kernelX, iterations = 1)

        contoursX = cv2.findContours(threshX, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contoursX = contoursX[0] if len(contoursX) == 2 else contoursX[1]
        rectsX = [cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in contoursX]
        print("number of contours: ", len(contoursX))


        image, x_labels = getProbableXLabels(image, rectsX, xaxis, yaxis, upper)
        white_bgX = 255 * np.ones_like(gray.copy())

        for (textx, texty, w, h) in x_labels:
            roi = gray[texty:texty + h, textx:textx + w]
            white_bgX[texty:texty + h, textx:textx + w] = roi


        x_labels_list = getXTextFromImageArray(white_bgX, 'x-labels')
        display_image_with_rects(image, rectsX)


        # Whiten x-labels and get x-text
        x_labels_list.sort(key = getXFromRect)
        print(x_labels_list)
        x_labels = []

        for text, (textx, texty, w, h) in x_labels_list:
            roi = 255 * np.ones_like(gray[texty:texty + h, textx:textx + w])
            gray[texty:texty + h, textx:textx + w] = roi
            x_labels.append(text)

        x_text_list = getXTextFromImageArray(gray, 'x-text')

        # Sort bounding rects by y coordinate
        def getXFromRect(item):
            return item[1][0]

        x_text_list.sort(key = getYFromRect)
        for text, (textx, texty, w, h) in x_text_list:
            x_text.append(text)


    # Get the x-labels by finding the maximum
    # intersections with the sweeping line
    maxIntersection = 0
    maxList = []
    for i in range(y1, 1000):
        count = 0
        current = []
        for index, rect in enumerate(contours):
            if lineIntersectsRectY(i, rect):
                count += 1
                current.append(contours[index])

        if count > maxIntersection:
            maxIntersection = count
            maxList = current

    return image, maxList



def maskImageBackwardPassX(filepath, end_idx):
    if path.name.endswith('.png') or path.name.endswith('.jpg') or path.name.endswith('.jpeg'):

        filepath = img_dir + "/" + path.name
        image = cv2.imread(filepath)
        height, width, channels = image.shape

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        while end_idx < height:
            if sum(gray[end_idx, :] < 200) == 0:
                break
            else:
                end_idx += 1

        gray[0:end_idx, :] = 255

        return gray

I hope the numbers and labels are clearly separated.
